# Running Dataflow Flex template poll time out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I have two service accounts with exact same roles under the same project and one can run the Flex template without any issue but the other fails to do so and returns:

`Timeout in polling result file: <LOGGING_BUCKET>. Service account: <SERVICE_ACCOUNT> Image URL: <IMAGE_URL> Troubleshooting guide at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#timeout-polling`

The SA that fails to run doesn't write the logs to GCS bucket, making it really difficult to debug. The graph doesn't get created and seems to get stuck at `queue` stage. The roles of both SAs are:

```
BigQuery Admin
Bigtable User
Dataflow Developer
Editor
Storage Object Viewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if is it obvious...but

- Have you checked the google doc from the error? (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#timeout-polling).
- Both SAs have the same roles?
- Let's say that SA1 can run Flex1, and SA2 can't run Flex2. Have you tried to assign SA1 into Flex2?
- What could be any possible difference between both SAs?
- If you create SA3 with the same roles as SA2 and assign it to Flex2, does it work?

Good luck